# Compiling libmemcached in OpenSolaris/OpenIndiana

Tags: makefile, libmemcached, opensolaris, libmemcache, openindiana

I wish to compile libmemcached into OpenIndiana OS. The configure process works perfectly with the following output

```
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating libhashkit/hashkitcon.h
config.status: creating libhashkit-1.0/configure.h
config.status: creating libtest/version.h
config.status: creating libtest/yatlcon.h
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating docs/source/conf.py
config.status: creating libmemcached-1.2/configure.h
config.status: creating support/libmemcached.pc
config.status: creating support/libmemcached.spec
config.status: creating mem_config.h
config.status: mem_config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
---
Configuration summary for libmemcached version 1.1.0

   * Installation prefix:       /usr/local
   * System type:               pc-solaris2.11
   * Host CPU:                  i386
   * C Compiler:                cc: Sun C 5.10 SunOS_i386 2009/06/03
   * C Flags:                   -g 
   * C++ Compiler:              c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
   * C++ Flags:                 -g -O2 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-pragmas -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Wvarargs -Waddress -Warray-bounds -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wformat-y2k -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wlogical-op -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wnormalized=id -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wswitch-enum -Wtrampolines -Wundef -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -funsafe-loop-optimizations -Wc++11-compat -Wclobbered -Wunused -Wunused-result -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-local-typedefs -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-security -fwrapv -pipe -fPIE -pie -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wpacked
   * CPP Flags:                 
   * LIB Flags:                 
   * Assertions enabled:        no
   * Debug enabled:             no
   * Shared:                    yes
   * Warnings as failure:       no
   * SASL support:              no
   * make -j:                   2
   * VCS checkout:              no
```

However when I try to compile using the make command I get this error output

```
gmake[2]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
  CC       libmemcached/libmemcached_libmemcached_la-array.lo
  CXX      libmemcached/libmemcached_libmemcached_la-auto.lo
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/stat.h", line 40: (struct) tag redeclared: memcached_stat_st
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/result.h", line 44: (struct) tag redeclared: memcached_result_st
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 57: (enum) tag redeclared: memcached_server_state_t
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 58: identifier redeclared: MEMCACHED_SERVER_STATE_NEW
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 59: identifier redeclared: MEMCACHED_SERVER_STATE_ADDRINFO
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 60: identifier redeclared: MEMCACHED_SERVER_STATE_IN_PROGRESS
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 61: identifier redeclared: MEMCACHED_SERVER_STATE_CONNECTED
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 62: identifier redeclared: MEMCACHED_SERVER_STATE_IN_TIMEOUT
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 63: identifier redeclared: MEMCACHED_SERVER_STATE_DISABLED
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/server.h", line 66: (struct) tag redeclared: memcached_server_st
"./libmemcached-1.2/struct/sasl.h", line 46: (struct) tag redeclared: memcached_sasl_st
"./mem_config.h", line 9: #error: "You should include mem_config.h as your first include file"
cc: acomp failed for libmemcached/array.c
gmake[2]: *** [Makefile:5645: libmemcached/libmemcached_libmemcached_la-array.lo] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

What do I need to do to overcome this stumbling block in the compile process? Thanks in advance for any help I can receive.

Comment: Try `gmake CPPFLAGS="-include mem_config.h"` to force an early include of mem_config.h, as the error message suggests.

Comment: Im afraid your strategy doesnt work. What else can I do?